# .xccheckout' remains in conflict

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

On committing code. It gives me following error.

**MyProject.xcodeproj/MyProject.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/MyProject.xccheckout' remains in conflict**

Can anybody help me solving it ?? Please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In terminal go to the specific path and reach your `MyProject.xccheckout` file (MyProject.xcodeproj/MyProject.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/MyProject.xccheckout)
- `svn resolved MyProject.xccheckout`
- you will get a svn message "`conflict resolved on this file`"

Now svn has resolved the conflict on that file and will allow you to commit the project ahead.

Answer (score 1):

try to use following command

svn resolved /file path